# System of congruences and Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find all the integers satisfying this system of congruences
$$\begin{cases}
x \equiv 2 \pmod 5\\
x \equiv 1 \pmod {10}\\
x \equiv 0 \pmod 3
\end{cases}
$$

I think you use Chinese remainder theorem but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Hint:  $\ x\equiv 1\pmod{10}\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 1\pmod 5\ \ $

Comment: In general, if your moduli are not relatively prime, there will be restrictions on the residue classes like the one Bill mentions.

Comment: So is there no way of changing it so that it can be solved using Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @Jack: you can change some of the numbers; for example, if you had $x\equiv7\pmod{10}$ instead of $1$, then there would be a solution.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Also if this were to have solutions then would you use Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: And can you not use Chinese remainder theorem because the modulus are not pairwise co prime?

Comment: @Jack: The Chinese Remainder Theorem says that there is a solution, but I would use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to actually get a solution.

Comment: But for this system there are no solutions??? Could you show me how to use either Chinese remainder or Extended Euclidean algorithm if possible?

Comment: @Jack: Knowing that $$\begin{align}x&\equiv2\pmod5\\ x&\equiv7\pmod{10}\end{align}$$ we can use the equivalent $$\begin{align}x&\equiv2\pmod5\\ x&\equiv1\pmod2\end{align}$$ where the moduli *are* relatively prime

Comment: @Jack: as shown by Bill and lab, there are no solutions to the system as given.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As, $5|10,$

$$x\equiv1\pmod{10}\implies x\equiv1\pmod5$$

Again we have $x\equiv2\pmod 5$

But $1\not\equiv2\pmod5$

Hence there will be no solution

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ x\equiv 1\pmod{10}\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 1\pmod 5\ $ contra $\ x\equiv 2\pmod 5$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally we can employ the following criterion for *existence* of a solution

$$\begin{array}{} x\equiv a_1 \pmod{\!m_1 }\\ \quad \vdots \\ x\equiv a_k\pmod{\!m_k} \end{array}\  \text{is solvable}\ \iff\  \color{#c00}{a_i\equiv a_j}\!\!\!\! \pmod{\!\gcd(m_i,m_j)}\ \text{ for all }\ i,j$$

$(\Rightarrow)\ $ has an easy proof: $ $ if $\, d = \gcd(m_i,m_j)\,$ then $\,d\mid m_i,m_j\,$ so  $\ {\rm mod}\ d\!:\ \color{#c00}{a_i\equiv x\equiv a_j}\ $

Answer (score 0):

Basically the two equivalences
\begin{align}
    x &\equiv a \pmod A \\
    x &\equiv b \pmod B
\end{align}
have a common solution if and only if $$a \equiv b \pmod{\gcd(A,B)}$$

In the case of \begin{align}
x &\equiv 2 \pmod 5\\
x &\equiv 1 \pmod {10}\\
x &\equiv 0 \pmod 3
\end{align}

We notice that $1 \not \equiv 2 \pmod{\gcd(5,10)}$, so there is no common solution to all three equivalences.

Another method is to reduce each equivalence into prime-power congruences and then remove redundant equivalneces. If there are no contradictory congruences , what you are left with is amenable to the regular CRT.

for your problem, $x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ are already prime-power congruences. Since $10 = 2 \times 5$ we can break $x \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ into the two prime-power congruences

\begin{align}
    x &\equiv 1 \pmod {2} \\
    x &\equiv 1 \pmod {5}
\end{align}

and we notice that $x \equiv 1 \pmod {5}$ and $x \equiv 2 \pmod {5}$ contradict each other. So, again, we know that the system of congruences has no common solution.